# JOIN with SQLite.swift

Tags: swift, sqlite.swift

I'm trying to run a fairly complex SQL JOIN using SQLite.swift, and have the results put into an array. Assigning the results of a select to an array works without a problem but I'm not sure if this is the correct or best method for executing such a join.

```
var results = [Row]()
results = Array(try db.execute("SELECT id, title, (SELECT name FROM books_authors_link AS bal JOIN authors ON(author = authors.id) WHERE book = books.id) authors, (SELECT name FROM publishers WHERE publishers.id IN (SELECT publisher from books_publishers_link WHERE book=books.id)) publisher, (SELECT rating FROM ratings WHERE ratings.id IN (SELECT rating from books_ratings_link WHERE book=books.id)) rating, (SELECT format FROM data WHERE data.book=books.id) formats, path FROM books"))
```

results.count ends up as 0.

Comment: Use sqlite.swift's `join` method.